# createElement('canvas') code works on Safari but not on Firefox, Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cross-browser, drawimage

I am trying a simple query which gets an image, and loads its data into a variable.
This code works on Safari(5), but doesn't work on Firefox(3.6.3 for Mac) or Chrome(10 for Mac).

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/saTzx/

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Another question related to this code is, shouldn't drawImage() actually draw the image? This doesn't happen in any of the browsers.

Comment: When you say "shouldn't drawImage() actually draw the image?" do you mean onscreen? Well, you haven't added the `<canvas>` element to the document anywhere, so the image drawn will not be visible...

Comment: btw. It helps a lot when you actually print out the exception that is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image *is* drawn, you just never appended the canvas to any parent element (e.g. `document.body.appendChild(canvas)`).

I get "Failed to load image" (also, that isn't the real error, the image is loaded) in Safari too, and rightly so. You are trying to read image data tainted by an image without any appropriate [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers, which is the source of your error. Fix your headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eli. I also read your other post on "Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18" and it was very helpful.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the header has to be added on the server side HTTP headers. Or get a copy of the file to the local folder. There is nothing that can be done from the JS itself? (I tried somethings on the lines of https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control but they didn't seem to help.

Comment: You don't have to use CORS if you're only requesting images that are located on the same domain, but you will need to if you are requesting images on other domains. A workaround is to use a proxy on the same domain.